# JPAMapStore missing in latest version of Hibernate-Spring

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hazelcast

JPAMapStore missing in latest version of Hibernate-Spring.

Its Available in hazelcast-spring-3.2.4.jar, However i am not able to find it latest version of Hibernate-Spring.

I am trying to use JPA based Mapstore for my Spring Boot Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was deleted [long time ago](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/commit/f733ea6c8d1ac71c3b566c66983bdeacf2209c0d) and moved to [Hazelcast Code Samples](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/v3.12.6/hazelcast-integration/spring-data-integration/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spring/jpa/JPAMapStore.java). It's not strictly related to core Hazelcast, so you can write it on your own or just copy from the Code Samples.

Some other related resources:

- [Hazelcast JPA Code Sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/v3.12.6/hazelcast-integration/spring-data-jpa-hazelcast-migration)
- [Hazelcast JPA Example](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/v3.12.6/hazelcast-integration/spring-data-hazelcast-chemistry-sample)
- [Hazelcast Spring Data Module](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast)